# What is the proper way of passing a vector?

Tags: c++

Im on year 10 and our teacher wants us to create an original project and using pointers

What I want to do is to create Members and be able to sort the members by there names and print them

When I run my code it says Invalid Access

*Team.h*

```
#ifndef TEAM_H
#define TEAM_H
#include "Staff.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;

class Team: public Staff
{
    public:
        Team();
        ~Team();
        vector<Staff *> &getVector();
    private:
        vector<Staff *> myStaffs;
};
#endif // TEAM_H
```

*Team.cpp*

```
    Team::Team()
    {
        for(unsigned int iStaff = 0; iStaff < myStaffs.size(); iStaff++)
        {
            myStaffs[iStaff] = createStaff(iStaff);
        }
    }

    vector<Staff*>& Team::getVector()
    {
        return myStaffs;
    }
```

Command class will do the sorting of team and print all team members

*Command.cpp*

```
void Command::printStaffs(vector<Staff*>&myStaffs)
{
    for(unsigned int iStaff = 0; iStaff < myStaffs.size(); iStaff++)
    {
        std::cout << "Staff ID number: "<<  myStaffs[iStaff]->getStaId()    << std::endl
                  << "Staff Skills 1: " << *myStaffs[iStaff]->getStaSkill() << std::endl
                  << "Staff Skills 2: " << *myStaffs[iStaff]->getStaSkill() << std::endl
                  << "Staff Skills 3: " << *myStaffs[iStaff]->getStaSkill() << std::endl
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

*Command.h*

```
#ifndef CommandH
#define CommandH
#include "Team.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;

class Command: public Team
{
    public:
         Command(){}
        ~Command(){}
        void sortVector(vector<Staff* >&vectorTemp);
        void printStaffs(vector<Staff* >&);
    private:
        vector<Staff *> vectEmployee;
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Team.h"
#include "Command.h"


int main()
{

    Team t;
    Command c;

    c.printStaffs(t.getVector());
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

*Staff.h*

```
#ifndef STAFF_H
#define STAFF_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using std::rand;
class Staff
{
    public:
        Staff();
        ~Staff();

        static Staff* createStaff(int); // creates staffs
        int** getStaSkill();
        int getStaId();            // returns Staff ID
        static int genRanNum(int); //Generate random number

    private:
        int *staSkill[3];
        int staId;

        //int staDeptAsigned;
};

#endif
```

*Staff.cpp*

```
#include "Staff.h"

Staff::Staff()
{
    *staSkill = new int[3];
}

Staff *Staff::createStaff(int s)
{
    Staff *staff = new Staff();
    staff->staId = s;
    *(staff->staSkill[0]) = genRanNum(10);
    *(staff->staSkill[1]) = genRanNum(10);
    *(staff->staSkill[2]) = genRanNum(10);
    return staff;
}

int** Staff::getStaSkill()
{
    return staSkill;
}

int Staff::getStaId()
{
    return staId;
}

int Staff::genRanNum(int num)
{
    return 1 +(std::rand()%num);
}

Staff::~Staff(){}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `Command::printStaffs` ?

Comment: printStaffs is on Command

Comment: where does it say invalid access, which line. If you dont know, run the program under a debugger. You dont say what platform you are on so I cant tell you how to use a debugger

Comment: @Jakelee just [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33160593/edit) to add the new code

Comment: When I pass the vector It says that the size of the vector is 0

Comment: @Jakelee You didn't understand the question. Where are you calling the 'Command::printStaffs' from?

Comment: The `Team` constructor has a problem. You are trying to index into an empty vector, use `push_back` instead.

Comment: Oh, the code is actually fine...sorry.

Comment: Ill try to check where the problem is

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Im calling it in Main.cpp

Comment: @Jakelee, well, since it is empty. You aren't creating any elements in your vector in Team class. You are iterating through the vector, but the vector is empty, since it was just created.

Comment: @Jakelee And where is the code, for your call to that method? You didn't show to us **how** you are calling it.

Comment: The team constructor is odd. `iStaff < myStaffs.size()` `myStaffs.size()` is guaranteed to be zero since nothing could possibly have been put into it yet.

Comment: Instead of `vector<Staff*>&myStaffs` make that `vector<Staff*> const& myStaffs` since you're not modifying it. There are general advantages to this convention, even though nothing specific for the code you have. I think this question and code belongs on Code Review instead of here.'

Comment: sigh - they never , ever teach debugging in CS classes

Comment: @pm100 I had a Comp Sci instructor who, when asked about debugging, recommended writing the code properly in the first place and refused to cover the topic at all. It was beneath him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct a `Team`, you have the following constructor:

```
Team::Team()
{
    for(unsigned int iStaff = 0; iStaff < myStaffs.size(); iStaff++)
    {
        myStaffs[iStaff] = createStaff(iStaff);
    }
}
```

However, `myStaffs` is a member of `Team` and gets [default constructed as empty](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), so nothing happens here since `myStaffs.size() == 0`.

Calling `printStaffs` on this `Team::getVector()` will correctly inform you that the `vector` is empty:

```
int main()
{
    Command c;
    Team t; // t.myStaffs will be empty
    c.printStaffs(t.getVector()); // passes an empty vector to printStaffs
    return 0;
}
```

You *might* want to pass a number to your `Team` constructor to create that many staffs:

```
Team::Team(int number_of_staff)
{
    for(unsigned int iStaff = 0; iStaff < number_of_staff; iStaff++)
    {
        myStaffs.push_back(createStaff(iStaff));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Command c;
    Team t(5); // t.myStaffs will contain 5 staff members
    c.printStaffs(t.getVector()); // passes vector of 5 staff
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jakelee Then you should consider accepting and upvoting his answer.